# Java Submenu ActionListener Does Not Work Properly

Tags: java, swing, events, actionlistener, submenu

I added right-click submenu to my program with the following code,

```
JPopupMenu pmenu = new JPopupMenu("Menu");

            JMenu sectionsMenu = new JMenu("Tickness"); 
            JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("1 px", gif1);
            menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    editStroke(e, finalResult);
                }
            });
            sectionsMenu.add(menuItem1);

            JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("2 px", gif2);
            menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    editStroke(e, finalResult);
                }
            });
            sectionsMenu.add(menuItem2);


            JMenuItem menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("3 px", gif2);
            menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    editStroke(e, finalResult);
                }
            });
            sectionsMenu.add(menuItem3);

pmenu.add(sectionsMenu);
pmenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
```

And edit strokemethod is

```
        private void editStroke(ActionEvent e, Linez finalResult) {
            System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        }
```

but when I compile and right click to somewhere, only "1 px" link is working and when I click the other links, nothing happens. What is more, when I click "1 px" the output is

> 1 px 1 px 1 px

How should I solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a copy-paste error. All three items are

`menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){`